# Combine csv files and add filename as new variable

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

There is file list as below,

```
"2022-01-07.csv" 
"2022-01-11.csv"
 "2022-01-14.csv"
 "2022-01-21.csv" 
"2022-02-08.csv" 
"2022-02-17.csv" 
"2022-02-21.csv"
```

Use following code can combine them and add filename variable at the combine process

```
 library(tidyverse)
    files <- list.files()
    i <- 1
    total_file <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:length(files)){
       single_file <- read.csv(files[i])
       single_file$filename <- files[i]
      total_file<- bind_rows(total_file,single_file)
    }
```

I know map can combine all of them into a list ,but can add file name as variable.
Is there easy methon for this ? Thanks!

Comment: Try `names(files) <- files; total_file <- lapply(files, read.csv) |> bind_rows(.id = "filename")`, i.e. name the list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr` and `dplyr` you could do the below:

```
files %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% #sets the name of the list element
  map(read.csv) %>% #using map to read the data
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "file_name") #bind the dataframes together
```